# .NET Webapplication - ComboBox doesn't work?

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm just trying to make a really simple static `ComboBox` in a cshtml site. I'm doing:

```
    <form>
        <ComboBox Text="Choose" id=txtName>
            <ComboBoxItem MouseMove="OnHover" Name="This">This</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem MouseMove="OnHover" Name="That">That</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem MouseMove="OnHover" Name="Other">Other</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <input type=submit id=cmdSubmit value=Submit>
   </form>
```

However, all this does is:
[image]
Shouldn't this make a proper dropdown list? What am I missing here?

**I'd like to know why the ComboBox doesn't work, I don't want to know alternative solutions!**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<form>
  <cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mild" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Hot" Value="2" />
    </cc1:ComboBox>
</form>
```

Comment: But this is not a ComboBox. I wonder why my combobox is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  instead of

```
<select onmousemove="OnHover()">
     <option selected="selected">This</option>
     <option>That</option>
     <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

and for mouse move event you can write javascript as below:

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function OnHover() {
        counter++;
        console.log('Counter :- ' + counter);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay again, I don't care what I can use INSTEAD, I want to know why the ComboBox doesn't work!